# Concatenation of multiple absolute std::filesystem::path instances

Tags: c++, path, filesystems, c++17

Why is the result of concatenating the following paths `/c/d`?

```
std::filesystem::path{"/a"} / std::filesystem::path{"b"} / std::filesystem::path{"/c/d"}
```

My mental model so far had the resulting path set to `/a/b/c/d`. To my surprise, it was simply `/c/d`. Curious to know where I went wrong here. (And what the right mental model is)

Comment: [Why `"/c/d"` instead of `"c/d"`?](https://godbolt.org/z/Y9Tz7z3qc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/a` is an absolute path, and `b` is a relative path, so concatenating them will produce `/a/b`.

But `/c/d` is also an absolute path, so concatenating it with *anything* in front of it is basically a no-op, the absolute path will take priority, so the final result is just `/c/d`.

This is discussed in more detail on cppreference.com:

[std::filesystem::operator/(std::filesystem::path)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_slash)

> Concatenates two path components using the preferred directory separator if appropriate (see [operator/=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append) for details).
>
> Effectively returns `path(lhs) /= rhs`.

[std::filesystem::path::operator/=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append)

> `path& operator/=( const path& p );`
>
> If `p.is_absolute() || (p.has_root_name() && p.root_name() != root_name())`, then replaces the current path with p as if by `operator=(p)` and finishes.

To get the result you want, drop the leading `/` from `/c/d` to make it a relative path:

```
std::filesystem::path{"/a"} / std::filesystem::path{"b"} / std::filesystem::path{"c/d"}
```

Answer (score 1):

> what the right mental model is

`a / b` means "if `b` is not absolute, then it's relative to `a`".

This lets you have a "default" base directory, where the rhs is assumed to be located, if the path is not absolute.